# Find projections of a convex region

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

Consider the following convex region
$$
 \{x\in \mathbb{R}^K: Ax\leq b \}
$$
where $A$ is a known $m\times K$ matrix and $b$ is a known $m\times 1$ vector.

Let $x_i$ be the $i$-th element of $x$.

I want to find the minimum and maximum value of $x_i$ in the region (i.e., I want to find the projection of the region in the $i$-th dimension).

Which optimisation problem I should solve to get such min and max?

Comment: It is not that easy to state an explicit solution.  In praxis you would use the simplex algorithm to solve this.

Comment: @Meowdog Just to make sure I understood, is it correct that the two problems I should solve are: $\min_{x} e_i x \text{ s.t. } Ax\leq b$ and $\max_{x} e_i x \text{ s.t. } Ax\leq b$, where $e_i$ is a vector with $1$ in the $i$-th position and the rest  zero. I can solve the two problems in Matlab, for instance by using the built-in package "linprogr".

Comment: Yes, that is correct.